OpenTelemetry tracing with Debezium and Kafka Connect
I'm working on a Node.js application and need to implement tracing to monitor interactions with another service that consumes messages from Kafka, following the outbox pattern.
Is it possible to implement tracing in this context? If so, how can I achieve it?
I'm looking for guidance on whether I need to use custom solutions or if there are existing tools/libraries that can help with this. Any examples or references to documentation would be highly appreciated.
I tried to put some custom docker volumes and enviroments.
